# Load option automatically depending of ID don´t works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+----------+---------+
|     ID |  Nombre  | PadreID |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      1 | KENWORTH |       0 |
|      2 | VOLVO    |       0 |
|      3 | T6000    |       2 |
|      4 | T800     |       1 |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

And a select like this one:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected.ID" ng-options="item.ID as item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>
```

I charge it using a function like:

```
 function cargarCatalogo() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/",
                null,
                function(res) {
                    $scope.Catalogos = res.data;


                    $scope.selected.ID = $scope.padreID;

                    $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
                },
                errorCatalogo);
        }
```

I want to get selected of my database for example if I click edit into `T6000` it have `PadreId = 2` so I selected should be `VOLVO` who has `ID = 2` but if I edit T800 with `PadreId = 1` selected should be KENWORTH who has `ID = 1` but it just throw blank option like this:

[image]

Note: when I click edit   `$scope.padreID` value is 2 so my default option need to be VOLVO but I just keep getting white option.

I don´t really don´t know what is wrong there, I really read alot of answers about it, but I can´t make it work.Help is very appreciatted. Regards

Comment: Depending on how you're making your HTTP request to get the data, Angular might not know it's supposed to digest. Have you tried wrapping the `$scope.selected.ID = $scope.padreID` in a $timeout() with no timeout specified? This is a hack in Angular 1.x to force a digest.

Comment: You say something like:  `$timeout($scope.selected.ID = $scope.padreID)`? @LouisK

Comment: `$timeout(function() { $scope.selected.ID = $scope.padreID })`

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're doing to change the `$scope.padreID` value, the assignment of `$scope.selected.ID = $scope.padreID` might not be working exactly as expected due to the timing of the digest cycle.

Comment: `$scope.padreID` is just value of padreID of selected register to edit

Comment: In your example you show `ng-model="selected.ID"` - is `$scope.padreID` set in the `$scope.filtro` method?

Comment: Yes, is something wrong? @LouisK

Comment: Did adding the $timeout work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149539/discussion-between-louisk-and-ledwing).